# load data to plist with NSKeyedUnarchiver

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i build an app that save data to plist, i used the belwo code :

```
self.emaillist = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Email.plist"];


self.emaillist = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:finalPath];
```

and when the app comes to the last line it got crashed.

Comment: what do u want to do? get data from .plist file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSBundle` have convenience method for finding the path for a resource like so:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Email" 
                                                 ofType:@"plist"];
```

Armed with this path you also have a convenience method for extracting the property list. If you know the root of the plist is an array then just use:

```
NSArray* plist = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.emails = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:plist];
```

Equivalent methods exist for dictionaries and strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the NSKeyedArchiver, not the unarchiver, to save data to a file.

Comment: i made a mistake,i want to load data from a file

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that your path is correct. I assume that your Plist is in the app's resources? In that case, the path to it would be:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Email" ofType:@"plist"]
```